# Sorting methods in the same order as an implementing interface in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for a way to sort the methods in a class in the same way as they are ordered in the interface they are overriding.

It's a class only implementing methods from one interface so they shouldn't be any problems.

I found the basic sorting functionality from Eclipse, but, as far as I found out, it can only sort with respect to the method type and the method name.

Any ideas? Eclipse plugins?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's not possible for Eclipse. But if what you want is organize a project that you have, you can rename all the methods of the interface by adding a char to each member, sort all the classes, and rename back the interface. Got it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the interface source also, use Source->Sort members on **both the interface and the class**. Afterwards they have the same order of methods.

I'm still wondering what you are trying to reach by sorting the code, as I see no necessity for that, because

- You can have the outline sorted, so the *logical* structure can be shown as you want it, independent of the file content.
- I can also not see a need to compare the two files textually, as the compiler will always tell you whether or not they match.

Comment: It is because I had an interface that grouped the methods by some sort of category. But that the interface got expanded. So after using the "Add unimplemented methods" function, they were all added at the end so the categorial sorting got a mess.
Will try your solution in a second.

Comment: I see what you mean with it, but in your proposal, the original order of the interface is lost as well. Thanks anyway